# JSPDF how to use variable fonts

Tags: jspdf

I can happily use jspdf to add fonts to a pdf. For that so far I add a font for regular, one for italic, one for bold and one for bolditalic in my case.

Now I have some fonts that do not provide these different fonts but variable ttf-fonts and I struggle to use those with JSPDF.

So far my solution goes like this:

```
pdf.addFileToVFS(`${fontFamily}-bold.ttf`, fontBase64Data);
pdf.addFont(`${fontFamily.ttf}-bold.ttf, fontFamily, 'bold', 700);
```

where I read fontBase64 data from file (which works nicely for regaulr, italic etc) and do the same with the regular and italic fonts...

For variable fonts I tried to add a font with variable font weight with above code just use the fontBase64Data as I read it from the ttf file of variable font.

However that just leaves the font regular.

To my understanding that alos makes sense as the API of addFonts seems to associate a loaded font with a font weight it represents, but does not seem to apply a font weight to the font.

Since I want to use variable fonts however I seem to need to either

- set a font as variable font, so weight would be automatically applied
- apply a weight to the variable font via api and then define that as bold

So far I couldn't find any of that. Am I missing sth or are variable font weights currently not supported yet by jspdf?

Cheers
Tom